# Cross Product of two perpendicular vectors

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Say I have two perpendicular vectors $\bf a$ and $\bf b$, and any vector $\bf c$, can anything be said about $(\bf a \times \bf b) \dot \bf c$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#

Comment: Will this be $0$?

Comment: Because $(\bf a \times \bf b) \dot \bf c$ is equal to $(\bf a \times \bf c) \dot \bf b$ and so it is perpendicular to both $\bf c$ and $\bf a$ does this mean it's in the same direction as $\bf b$ or is that a stupid observation? Seems wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on Wikipedia:

> Geometrically, the scalar triple product $$a \cdot (b \times c)$$ is the (signed) volume of the parallelepiped defined by the three vectors given.

If what you want to know is the relation $c$ has with $a$ and $b$.
The most evident is that if $(a \times b) \cdot c = 0$ then the three vectors must be coplanar.